# URL Rewrite - $_GET variable not passing through

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple rewrite that changes

```
http://website.com/page.php?id=1
```

into

```
http://website.com/page/1
```

using the following rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The rewrite works, it displays the page (i don't get a 404), but it doesn't appear to be passing through the id from the URL.

To test this I basically echoed the $_GET['id'] and nothing was returned.

Does anyone know why I might be going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and show us what you get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely due to enabling of `MultiViews` which runs before `mod_rewrite` and rewrites `/page to /page.php`.

Add this line on top of your .htaccess to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```